# NameError: uninitialized constant SSHKit::Logger::ANY

Tags: capistrano, capistrano3, sshkit

Whenever I `cap production deploy`, I get the following error:

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant SSHKit::Logger::ANY
```

Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'
require 'capistrano/deploy'
require "capistrano/scm/git" #If using 3.9.0
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git #If using 3.9.0
```

myproject.rb: https://gist.github.com/LeoNero/f34d59c60eb169dc83e9612283253ee6

I'm using SSHKit 1.7.1 and Capistrano 3.4.0 (I've tested with 3.90 and 3.5.0 and I get the same error...)

How can I solve it?

Comment: I'd suggest by upgrading to latest Capistrano/SSHKit, trying again, and then posting that error message if the issue still persists.

Comment: @will_in_wi I still get the same error

Comment: I'll add `myproject.rb` to the description

Comment: What does your Capfile contain?

Comment: @will_in_wi I've just updated my answer :)

Comment: Any ideas? :DDD

Comment: I'm using ruby 2.4.1

Comment: I'm not sure at this point. I'd suggest building another basic app that you can post to GitHub which replicates your issue. That would allow others to download it and try it themselves.